# Creating a function to describe a set of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, function

I want to create a function which will give the output of df.describe for all the dataframes which is passed to the function argument.

My idea was to store all the dataframe(whom i need to describe) names as columns in a seperate dataframe (x) and then pass this to the function.

Here is what i have made and the output :
The problem is that its only showing description of only one dataframe

```
def des(df):
columns = df.columns
for column in columns:

    column=pd.read_csv('SKUs\\'+column+'.csv')
    column['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(column['Date'].astype(str),dayfirst = True, format ='%d&m%y',infer_datetime_format=True)
    column.dropna(inplace=True)

return(column.describe())
```

```
data = {'UGCAA':[],'FAPG1':[],'ACSO5':[],'LGHF2':[],'LGMP8':[],'GGAF1':[]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

des(df)

```
        Sales
count   948.000000
mean    876.415612
std     874.373236
min     1.000000
25%     298.750000
50%     619.500000
75%     1148.500000
max     7345.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can create list of `DataFrame`s and last `concat` together:

```
def des(df):
    dfs = []
    for column in df.columns:

        df1=pd.read_csv('SKUs\\'+column+'.csv')
        df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].astype(str),
                                     format ='%d%m%y',infer_datetime_format=True)
        df1.dropna(inplace=True)
        dfs.append(df1.describe())

    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=df.columns)
```

Comment: I am getting an error when following your code.
--------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-3e47b4623e9b> in <module>
----> 1 des(df)

<ipython-input-120-a47b429b86af> in des(df)
      3     for coloumn in df.columns:
      4 
----> 5         df=pd.read_csv('SKUs\\'+coloumn+'.csv')
      6         df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].astype(str),
      7                                      format ='%d%m%y',infer_datetime_format=True)

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: I've prepared the df as below:


data=['ACSO5','UGCAA','FAPG1','LGHF2','LGMP8','GGAF1']
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are looping over and reseting column each time while only returning one. To just visualize it, you can just print the `describe` in each loop, or store them together in one variable and handle it after the loop.

```
def des(df):
    columns = df.columns
    for column in columns:

        column=pd.read_csv('SKUs\\'+column+'.csv')
        column['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(column['Date'].astype(str),dayfirst = True, format ='%d&m%y',infer_datetime_format=True)
        column.dropna(inplace=True)
        print(column.describe())
```